# How to display capture/gallery image in next activity like slide show

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I want to display capture/gallery image in next activity and the images should show like this  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dietcoacher.sos&hl=en, i have mentioned my code which i have tried for gallery it is working fine, Capture image is not working.Please help me...

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            //file path of captured image
            imagepath = cursor.getString(columnIndex); 
            //file path of captured image
            File f = new File(imagepath);
            String filename = f.getName();

            Toast.makeText(Contact.this, "Your Path:"+imagepath, 2000).show();
            Toast.makeText(Contact.this, "Your Filename:"+filename, 2000).show();
            cursor.close();
            Log.i("image path", imagepath);
            Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);


        }


            else if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
                //Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getData().getPath(); 

                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                imagepath = getPath(selectedImageUri, null);
               Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);


          // bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"); 

         Intent i = new Intent (Contact.this, NewContact.class);
        i.putExtra("data",bitmap);
                startActivity(i);
               // messageText.setText("Uploading file path:" +imagepath);

            }
        }
     }
```

LogCat

02-19 16:39:10.041: E/ActivityThread(32225): Activity com.sec.android.gallery3d.app.Gallery has leaked IntentReceiver com.sec.samsung.gallery.view.albumview.AlbumViewState$21@42cc6710 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
02-19 16:39:10.041: E/ActivityThread(32225): android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity com.sec.android.gallery3d.app.Gallery has leaked IntentReceiver com.sec.samsung.gallery.view.albumview.AlbumViewState$21@42cc6710 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
02-19 16:39:10.041: E/ActivityThread(32225):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.(LoadedApk.java:805)
02-19 16:39:10.041: E/ActivityThread(32225):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:606)
02-19 16:39:10.041: E/ActivityThread(32225):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1735)
02-19 16:39:10.041: E/ActivityThread(32225):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1715)
02-19 16:39:10.041: E/ActivityThread(32225):    at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1709)
02-19 16:39:10.041: E/ActivityThread(32225):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:453)
02-19 16:39:10.041: E/ActivityThread(32225):    at com.sec.samsung.gallery.view.albumview.AlbumViewState.registerNetworkStateReceiver(AlbumViewState.java:1404)
02-19 16:39:10.041: E/ActivityThread(32225):    at com.sec.samsung.gallery.view.albumview.AlbumViewState.onCreate(AlbumViewState.java:477)
02-19 16:39:10.041: E/ActivityThread(32225):    at com.sec.samsung.gallery.model.ViewStateProxy.startState(ViewStateProxy.java:73)
02-19 16:39:10.041: E/ActivityThread(32225):    at com.sec.samsung.gallery.controller.StartStateCmd.execute(StartStateCmd.java:27)
02-19 16:39:10.041: E/ActivityThread(32225):    at org.puremvc.java.core.Controller.executeCommand(Controller.java:138)
02-19 16:39:10.041: E/ActivityThread(32225):    at org.puremvc.java.core.Controller$1.onNotification(Controller.java:174)
02-19 16:39:10.041: E/ActivityThread(32225):    at org.puremvc.java.patterns.observer.Observer.notifyObserver(Observer.java:87)
02-19 16:39:10.041: E/ActivityThread(32225):    at org.puremvc.java.core.View.notifyObservers(View.java:134)
02-19 16:39:10.041: E/ActivityThread(32225):    at org.puremvc.java.patterns.facade.Facade.notifyObservers(Facade.java:376)
02-19 16:39:10.041: E/ActivityThread(32225):    at org.puremvc.java.patterns.facade.Facade.sendNotification(Facade.java:336)
02-19 16:39:10.041: E/ActivityThread(32225):    at org.puremvc.java.patterns.facade.Facade.sendNotification(Facade.java:350)

Comment: you can use swipe functonality for this..

Comment: Pass byte array or file path of image to your next Activity.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/ see this

Comment: How to pass bitmap to other activity???? i want to display capture and gallery image in next activity.

Comment: you have to convert your bitmap to byte Array and after that send it.

Comment: Can u show me the sample code..

Comment: Here i am using two bitmaps, for camera/gallery both images should show in one imageview in next activity..

Comment: you can declare global bitmap and use for both gallery and camera and pass that as per my answer.